# Rows added to gridview don't persist when save event is triggered

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview on my webpage that can have rows added dynamically. There is a for loop that adds the rows like this:

```
protected void AddNewJob(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(newJobCount.Text);i++)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            tr.Cells.Add(ServicesDDL("-- Select Service Type --"));
            tr.Cells.Add(JobsDDL("-- Select Job Type --"));
            tr.Cells.Add(TextBoxCell());
            tr.Cells.Add(TextBoxCell());
            tr.Cells.Add(TextBoxCell());

            assetTable.Rows.Add(tr);
        }          
    }
```

After the rows are added and changed from their default values the rows are looped through and data is saved to the database. I'm having problems getting the rows added to the gridview to persist and exist on the gridview when the page's save event is triggered. That code looks like this:

```
foreach (TableRow row in assetTable.Rows)
{

if (isFirst)
{
    isFirst = false;
    continue;
}

DropDownList service = (DropDownList)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
string assetText = service.SelectedItem.Value;
DropDownList jobDescription = (DropDownList)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
string serialText = jobDescription.SelectedItem.Value;
TextBox equipmentCount = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
string leaseText = equipmentCount.Text;
TextBox jobSize = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
string originText = jobSize.Text;
TextBox serialNo = (TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0];
string deliveryText = serialNo.Text;
string oNo = orderNo.Text;

if (assetText != "0" && serialText != "0")
{
    APICallClass.Job j = new APICallClass.Job();
    j.JobTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(serialText);
    j.serviceID = Convert.ToInt32(assetText);
    j.equipment = leaseText;
    j.jobSize = originText;
    j.serialNumbers = deliveryText;
    j.orderID = Convert.ToInt32(global.GlobalID);

    APICallClass.API.AddJob(j, Session["Variable"].ToString());
}
}
```

When the code pasted above runs, it only sees the rows that are pulled in from the database. I think my problem could be fixed by calling something like .databind() somewhere that I'm not, but I've tried a few places and they have not fixed the problem.

**Thanks in advance for any help, and helping me become a more robust ASP.NET developer.**

Comment: Could you not add those DropDownLists inside GridView at aspx page?

Comment: @Win I don't understand your question. Could you rephrase it please?

Comment: We don't normally add controls dynamically in GridView. They should be added at design time inside template inside aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

When a GridView is `DataBind()`-ed, the contents of the GridView are "rebuilt" based on the the GridView's `DataSource`. If you need the new row to stay in the GridView, either do not call `DataBind()` after the new row is added, or ensure that the contents of your new row are in the GridView's `DataSource` before future calls to `DataBind()`.

In a page I wrote once I had a similar situation and did the latter. The data for the initial rows was pulled from the database on the first page load and persisted in ViewState. As the user added, removed, and reordered rows in the GridView, the page just changed the data in ViewState and re-`DataBind()`ed the GridView.